# How to perform gridview edit with old filtering data in Asp.Net Dynamic data web application

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have an Asp. Net dynamic data web application page with a grid view and search filters provided for filtering data.
When user provide some search criteria and click on edit option the grid view without clicking on search button, the grid view is binding with data based on search criteria provided by the user.

Is there any workaround in this case to bind the grid view with original data instead of search results?

Thanks,

Praveen.

Answer (score 0):

yes if you look at the Page_Init method of the List page you will see this code below, change the middle line to GridView1.SetMetaTable(table); and you will not get the filter being passed to the edit/insert pages.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{
    table = DynamicDataRouteHandler.GetRequestMetaTable(Context);
    GridView1.SetMetaTable(table, table.GetColumnValuesFromRoute(Context));
    GridDataSource.EntityTypeFilter = table.EntityType.Name;

}